# Fetch certain information on click from api and have it stop after 10 clicks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am quite new to programming and am currently working with React.js and API.

I am trying to get this quiz API https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium to respond in my app.

So far I have fetched all the information that I need but on click I want the app to show whether I have clicked on correct_answer from json or incorrect_answer and have it show a textbox with information. After 10 clicks it should stop counting and show the results and this is where I'm stuck and would appreciate a bit of help.

This is what I got so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const API =
  "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=20&difficulty=medium";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      results: [],
      score: 0,
      correct_answer: "",
      incorrect_answers: ""
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1,
      correct_answer: event.target.value,
      incorrect_answers: event.target.value
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateAppWithData();
  }

  populateAppWithData() {
    const showData = fetch(API)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ results: data.results }));
    console.log(showData);
  }

  render() {
    var {} = this.state ? "You are correct" : "You are incorrect";
    console.log();
    const results = this.state.results.slice().map((result, index) => (
      <ul onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} key={"result" + index}>
        <li>
          <h2> {result.question}</h2>
          {""}
          <h5>{result.correct_answer}</h5>
        </li>
        {result.incorrect_answers.map(incAnswer => (
          <li>
            <h5>{incAnswer}</h5>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Quiz App</h1>
        <div>{results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)]}</div>
        <div>Score: {this.state.score}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just restart from scratch. As every question can be answered or unanswered, right or wrong, it has to have its own state. Therefore it has to be its own component. So let's build a `Question` component that takes a right and a few incorrect answers, and a question, and calls back if the question was answered:

```
  class Question extends Component {
    state = { answered: undefined, isRight: undefined };

    answerClicked(answer) {
       const { hasAnswered, correct_answer } = this.props;
       return event => {
         if(this.state.answered) return; // prevent answering twice
         const isRight = correct_answer === answer;
         hasAnswered(isRight); // propagate to parent
         this.setState({ answered: answer,  isRight });
       };
    }

    render() {
     const { question, correct_answer, incorrect_answers } = this.props;
     const { answered, isRight } = this.state;
      return (
       <div>
        {question}
        {[...incorrect_answers, correct_answers]/*shuffle?*/.map(answer => <div onClick={this.answerClicked(answer)} > {answer} </div>)}
       {answered && `You answered ${answered}`}
       {answered && isRight && "Thats right! :)"}
       {answered && !isRight && "That's wrong :/"}
      </div>
     );
    }
 }
```

So far so good. Now you can add:

```
  <Question question="Whats the answer to life the universe and everything?" correct_answer="42" incorrect_answers={["15", "12"]} hasAnswered={right => alert(right ? "Right" : "Wrong")} />
```

Somewhere, and see a question :)

---

Next Step: We want to group multiple questions and add a Counter. For that we use another component, that builds up `Question`s and maintains a counter in it's state, how many questions were answered already, and how many of them were answered right.

```
  class Questions extends Component {
    state = { right: 0, counter: 0 };

    questionAnswered(isRight) {
     this.setState(({ counter, right }) => ({ counter: counter + 1, right: right + isRight }));
    }

    render() {
      const { questions } = this.props;
      const { counter, right } = this.state;
      const unanswered = questions.length - counter;

      if(unanswered <= 0) {
        return `All answered!`;
      }

      return (
        <div>
         You have {unanswered} questions left, {right} are rigjt already!
         { questions.map(it => <Question key={it.question} {...it} hasAnswered={it => this.questionAnswered(it)} />) }
        </div>
     );
    }
 }
```

Now again we can test this part of the application easily:

```
  <Questions questions={[{ question: "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?", correct_answer: "42", incorrect_answers: ["52", "12"] }, /*...*/]} />
```

Now the only thing that is left is to let App load the questions and use the `<Questions />` component when the questions are available.

Through this split up, we do have a seperation of concerns:

The `<Question>` class manages anything related to asking the question and giving a "per question feedback"

The `<Questions>` component manages multiple questions and gives the overall feedback if all questions were answered.

The `<App>` component loads the questions.

Comment: Hi Jonas. It works perfect and has given me alot of ideas on how to fix the next few steps along the way. However one minor issue here is that the const unanswered = this.questions.length - counter gives me an error of "Cannot read property length of undefined"

Comment: Thank you so much!! it's working.. Now I'm just going to play around with it for a bit and make it work correctly with the data received from json and that I want to try by myself but you've made it so much easier. I really appreciate it!!